# mysql condition to select empty fulltext cell?

Tags: php, mysql, tags

i need write a select query to find the number of rows which have an empty fulltext field but for some reason both:

```
select count(id) from table where field is null;
```

and

```
select count(id) from table where field = "";
```

don't seem to work!

what else is there?!

Answer (score 1):

And if that doesn't work...  you might try

where len( trim( field )) = 0

Answer (score 0):

```
select
   count(id)
from
   table
where
   isnull(field);
```

However, your query with "field is null" should work to (and it does, for me at least).

Answer (score 0):

When you say they don't work, do you mean the empty and non-empty fields are returned or nothing is returned?

If you get empty and non-empty, try using PHP to test with the return is_null or is_string. Perhaps there is some whitespace in there or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
SELECT id, LENGTH(field) AS len, field
FROM table
```

and see if there's a non-zero string length on fields that do look "empty" and would otherwise match on your initial queries. If the length is non-zero, there's whitespace of some sort in there.